# Unicode Encode Error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019'

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to read html file but when sourcing out for the titles and urls to compare with my keyword `'alist'` I get this error `Unicode Encode Error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019'.` Error in link(http://tinypic.com/r/307w8bl/8)

Code

```
for q in soup.find_all('a'):
    title = (q.get('title'))
    url = ((q.get('href')))
    length = len(alist)
    i = 0
    while length > 0:
        if alist[i] in str(title): #checks for keywords from html form from the titles and urls
            r.write(title)
            r.write("\n")
            r.write(url)
            r.write("\n")
        i = i + 1
        length = length -1
doc.close()
r.close()
```

A little background. alist contains a list of keywords which I would use to compare it with title so as to get what I want. The strange thing is if alist contains 2 or more words, it would run perfectly but if there was only one word, the error as seen above would appear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a general rule, you should remember to include the **complete traceback** (not just the final error message), and indicate the Python version you are using (particularly useful for unicode questions, due to the differences between Python 2 and Python 3 in that regard).

Comment: Sorry a bit new to this. Python 2.7. Whats a/the complete traceback?

Comment: Complete traceback means full error description. Please copy paste what u get on console.

Comment: The traceback is the set of lines found above the error message, the first one being: `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: this is first line of traceback. Please give full traceback.

Comment: Hi I added the link for the error image. Couldn't upload here due to lack of reputation....

Comment: You don't need to convert `title` to a string, since its already a string. Replace `str(title)` with just `title`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your list MUST BE a string list, try to encode title var

```
>>> alist=['á'] #asci string
>>> title = u'á' #unicode string
>>> alist[0] in title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> title and alist[0] in title.encode('utf-8')
True
>>>
```

Comment: It returns a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: then title is null, you should check it before, have a look to my last edit

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `title` is a Unicode string that can contain any kind of character; `str(title)` tries to turn it into a bytestring using the ASCII codec, but that fails because your title contains a non-ASCII character.

What are you trying to do? Why do you need to turn the title into a bytestring?

Comment: alist contains keywords. I was planning to use the loop to search for the keywords from alist that could be found in title. Thus i need title to be a string.

Comment: title already is a Unicode string, that will work just fine with the keywoards. I think you can just remove the call to str()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `str(title)`. U are trying to convert `unicode` data to string.

Why u are converting `title` to string? You can direct access it.

[`soup.find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) will return you list of strings.

Comment: alist contains keywords. I was planning to use the loop to search for the keywords from alist that could be found in title. Thus i need title to be a string