# how to turn characters in wrong codec into space in python?

Tags: python, encoding

I need to read data from an external source, which is from MS.

As you know, MS likes to embed binary to simple text, so sometimes I run into trouble when I encounter such issue:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in
>   position 1833: ordinal not in range(128)

So my goal is, instead of this error, I want the text to be output to stdout anyway, but with all these wrong characters turned into white space.

Any idea how to do this? I hope it's not gonna be catch exception and a for loop to manually change it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you think encode sounds properer? or could you offer a better tag? when i describe this problem, i would say this is a **text encoding** issue. correct me.

Comment: I meant are you encoding the strings or is it just printing in a cmd shell that is causing the issue?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the same, output to stdout, or turn it from ascii to unicode. since this code itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: you could `u'\u2019'.encode("utf-8",errors="ignore")` but that won't add a space, tu'\u2019' is also a `’`

Comment: A similar problem was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737594/unicode-encode-error-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2019). One more thing: What about reading the file in binary mode and replacing desired characters?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's close. but em... i hope there could be some placeholder to show there was something here.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath how to search?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr,  where are you running the code from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham unix console.

Comment: what does `locale` output?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+replace+all+non-ascii

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yeah. that's a nice point.